How to boot linux kernel with cd rootfs using grub2?
I made a custom UEFI only bootable ISO file and loaded it to UTM VM. The rootfs is directly stored in the ISO, and I'm using grub2 as boot loader.  After I configured the linux, initrd and boot the image, the vm seems stuck forever, why?


The last message seems to be from the kernel EFI stub. Maybe the kernel does not have the correct console driver built in, and so is unable to produce any messages.
